# Using variables inside loops and if-statements in Java

Tags: java, variables

I have to complete a question.

The question is: *Write a program that takes the daily amount of sunlight hours(input of sunlight for each day) for the given amount(input of days) of days. Output the day with the highest amount of sunlight hours and the day with the lowest amount of sunlight hours.*

I have completed this question using a list, but my teacher said that she wants me to use a `nested loop` **or** a `loop` and `if` statement.

So far, I take the input of days and run a `while loop` to ask the user the amount of sunlight hours for each day. The problem is comparing inputs of each loop iteration (to find the highest and lowest total amount of sunlight of a day).

**CODE:**

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class temp {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner new_scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter the amount of days you wish to enter the daylight hours for: ");
                    int loop_num = new_scan.nextInt();

            for(int x=0; x<=loop_num;x++){ 

                //Here I ask the user to input the number of sunlight hours for each day, I don't know how to compare separate input iterations (to find the highest and lowest days of sunlight).

                System.out.println("Enter the number of daylight hrs for day "+ x);
                    int next_num = new_scan.nextInt();
                    int c = 0;
                    int old_num = c + next_num;

                            if(next_num>old_num){
                                int highest_num = next_num;
                            } else{ int highest_num = old_num; }


                            if(next_num<old_num){
                                int lowest_num = next_num;
                            } else{ int lowest_num = old_num; }

        }
            System.out.println("The lowest amount of sunlight of the days given was: "+ lowest_num);
            System.out.println("The highest amount of sunlight of the days given was: "+ highest_num);
    }
}
```

**My question is:** How can I compare iterations to find the amount of sunlight on the days with the highest and lowest amount of sunlight? 
In other words, how can I compare the input data of different iterations in a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable should be defined out of the loop to be persistent, otherwise it is recreated on each iteration.
You need something like that:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = -1;
for(int x=0; x<=loop_num;x++){ 

    System.out.println("Enter the number of daylight hrs for day "+ x);
    int next_num = new_scan.nextInt();

    if(next_num>max){
        max = next_num;
    } 
    if (nex_num <min) {
        min = nex_num;
    }

}
System.out.println("The lowest amount of sunlight of the days given was: "+ min);
System.out.println("The highest amount of sunlight of the days given was: "+ max);
```

I suggest to add the input sanity check here since the number should be within 0 - 24 hours range.

Comment: `int min = 0`, should be initialized with different value (probably `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

Comment: as a min value you should use infinity rather than 0. But the best idea is to use first readed value (the same with min value).

Comment: Thanks. Provided there hardly will be negative number of hours (or number over 24 hours) -1 should be enough. Anyway this should be part of input sanity check rather than further calculation.

Comment: Chosen because explained how the variable needs to be defined OUTSIDE the loop! Thank you.

Comment: @Zereges, you're completely right, of course. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner new_scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the amount of days you wish to enter the daylight hours for: ");
int loop_num = new_scan.nextInt();
int highest_num=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int lowest_num=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for(int x=0; x<=loop_num;x++){ 
     System.out.println("Enter the number of daylight hrs for day "+ x);
     int next_num = new_scan.nextInt();
      if(next_num > highest_num){
         highest_num  = next_num;
      }
      if(next_num < lowest_num){
         lowest_num  = next_num;
      }
 }
System.out.println("The lowest amount of sunlight of the days given was: "+ lowest_num);
System.out.println("The highest amount of sunlight of the days given was: "+ highest_num);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is going to rely in not having an adequate scope. Any variables created inside of a loop are only good while you're in that iteration of the loop, when you pass along to the next iteration all that information that you just assigned to the newly created integer value gets copied over with a new integer value. Also, in applications like this using the Scanner module for inputs I usually tend to use System.out.print("Input goes here: ") so that the the user (or instructor) can enter input on the same line instead of the next line.

Answer (score 0):

An note please. Java naming convention has it that you begin class names with an uppercase character. Not that your codes won't compile or run if you don't. It's just a good programming practice.